# Usergrid fulltext search

Tags: apigee, usergrid

I am using APIGEE (apigee.com ) usergrid js lib and I am new in this technology
I have make function  for search record 'full text search' below is my code

brands.setQueryParams({"ql":"select * where brand  contains '"+searchItem+"' " , "limit":'9999' });
      brands.get(
         function() {
            //first empty out all the current brands in the list
             $("#t_body").remove();

after calling this function url hit apigee server like below

api.usergrid.com//sandbox/brands?ql=select%20*%20where%20bran‌​d%20%20contains%20%27Sam%27%20&limit=9999

but not record found but we have record into database

Answer (score 0):

The system doesn't support "full text search".  You can, however, use wildcards.  You have to postfix a "*" to the end of the string (won't work when the * is at the beginning or inside the string):

select * where brand contains 'foo*'

will match

{"brand":"foobar"}